# Using 'require' inside Node js to gain better performance

Tags: node.js, performance, v8, koa

I use a LOT of dependencies in my controllers. Is it a good suggestion to use something like below to increase performance slightly: (i.e. lazy loading for controllers)

```
app.use(route.get('/test', function(){
    c = require('./testcontroller')
    c.method();
}) );
app.use(route.get('/test2', function(){
    c2 = require('./testcontroller2')
    c2.method();
}) );
```

Rather than common method:

```
c = require('./testcontroller')
c2 = require('./testcontroller2')
//all other controllers

app.use(route.get('/test', c.method) 
app.use(route.get('/test2', c2.method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use `require()` inside a route handler or inside a middleware handler.  That's because `require()` uses synchronous I/O and you do not want to use synchronous I/O in any route handler.

The not-so-bad-news is that `require()` caches the result so it will only be a hit the first time the route is hit, but most server designers would rather take a little bit longer hit on server startup and not be using synchronous I/O at all in any route handlers or middleware.

So, there's a reason the common method is the common method and modules are usually loaded at server startup.  Presumably, this is a long running server process so you're not really saving anything in the long run by not loading a module.  If anyone ever uses it, it's going to get loaded sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the traditional way is better- you might require redundant stuff (probably not, as any controller will be used eventually), but on the other end- it will be required when the app restarts.

In my mind performance during run-time is more important than fast loading, in your first suggestion you require during run time.